# New Ubuntu user

Tags: command-line

I installed Ubuntu a week ago an I'm quite happy about how fast it works on my laptop. As a beginner I would like to know what commands are necessary if in the future any problems will appear . I know Linux is secure but there are possibilities to get viruses... in case that happens how I can detect it and remove it from my system?

In Windows if you have to do many downloads, files, games I know that after some time you need to make a defragmentation in other to make it run smoothly. How I do that on linux?

Again I'm a beginner... sorry for my English. I would like to know if there is a site where I can find all the necessary commands and information about this system. I really want to know more about Linux... I don't want to go back to Windows 10 not after seeing how fast this operating system is.

Comment: @Andrej Stan: It appears you got a huge number of questions -- which is cool. Unfortunately this makes it a little to broad for this format here. there are a lot of ubuntu wikis outside might a good starting point.

Comment: "I know Linux is secure". No it is MORE secure than windows. How secure depends on your actions. "but there are posibilites to get viruses" Not really.  There has not been a virus active as is can be active on Windows. Individual systems can get attacked and broken. But not all of us with 1 broken system.  "How I do that on linux?" There is no need for that. So you got some answers ;-) but you should really use the search on AU. Most of these type of questions have been beaten to death. Repeatedly.

Comment: Go to [most voted](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=votes) and [most frequent](http://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=frequent) questions here in this site, will answer most of your questions

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to using Ubuntu on laptop, but not new to linux.  As a life-long windows user, here are the things I do with a fresh install of Ubuntu that help a lot.  Depending on your interests, some of these ideas may be more/less helpful.  if you have questions about specific items, here, I recommend putting in new individual questions like mentioned in the comments already.

- Get a decent chat client like Slack.  Or if you are in to irc, you can run

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pidgin
  ```
- Remove the Libre Office included with 16.04

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
  ```
- Download Libre Office from libreoffice.org then install it

  ```
  tar xzvf filename_you_download_from_libreoffice.org
  cd the_folder_you_just_untarred/DEBS
  dpkg -i *.deb
  ```
- Install Unity Tweak Tool and vim.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
  sudo apt-get install vim
  ```
- Make sure you are up-to-date with patches

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  sudo apt-get clean all
  sudo apt-get clean update
  sudo apt-get clean upgrade
  ```
- Install Java and link plugin to firefox (if you need java in browser).  This article might help:

  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491322/how-to-add-java-plugin-for-firefox-on-linux
- Even if you are not a developer, consider getting a decent toolset for editing files and/or tinkering with stuffs

  https://www.jetbrains.com/
- Learn how to use these commands:  netstat, ps, grep, vmstat, top, wget, curl, history, vi, man, nslookup, traceroute, tar.  Some things I do daily:

  ```
  netstat -ant
  ps -ef |grep "name_of_service"
  vmstat 2
  wget http://www.google.com
  curl http://www.google.com
  ```
- My favorite linux sites:

  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/

  https://linuxacademy.com/

  https://askubuntu.com/
- Games - I personally haven't had much success with games beyond Minecraft.  Steam and Wine I find to be either too buggy, or the games the games don't pique my interest.  So you might want to consider dual booting if you determined to play games on your laptop.  Especially if you are looking for top-shelf titles like anything from Blizzard, Bethesda, etc.